# QGIS - Insert vertices on the straight line of the sides of a polygon with a specified distance

Tags: qgis, vertices, square

I have a square polygon, which has four sides and four vertices at its corners. But I need to insert vertices on each of the sides with a specific distance interval (every 100 meters or every 250 meters).

Can this be done automatically in QGIS?

The polygon can be seen below:

[image]

Comment: Please decide which software you're going to use. What have you tried? How should sides be handled, which can't be divided by 100/250?

Comment: I chose QGIS, because, apparently, it has more options

Comment: Hi, i don't know how to answer the question with more than the link to the documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#densify-by-interval

Comment: This documentation was very useful to me.